# Выравнивание в <div>

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой код:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="email">
   <a class="a" href="http://localhost/site/en" style="color: #FFFFFF">Switch to</a>
   <img class="chat" height="20" width="20" src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img0004.png">
   <img class="chat" height="20" width="20" src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img0003.png">
   <a class="a1" href="http://localhost/site/zayavka/" style="color: #FFFFFF">  Оставить заявку</a>
   <img class="chat" height="20" width="20" src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img0002.png">
   <a class="a" href="mailto:info@1.ru" style="color: #FFFFFF">  Обратная связь</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Как первую ссылку и картинку оставить слева, а оставшиеся четыре "предмета" выровнить по правому краю (один "предмет" за другим)? Т.е. чтобы было так

Надпись-картинка----------------------------------картинка-надпись-картинка-надпись

Comment: Нашел вариант с ипользованием position: . Другого не существует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописать элементам `float:right`, которые должны быть выровнены по правому краю

https://jsfiddle.net/5mz9x0v6/

Comment: Спасибо большое за `float:`!!! Чтобы поменьше мучаться диву дал `align="right"`. А два "предмета" именно флоатом и перенес!